# Can feature tools save feature list directly to s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, featuretools

I'm trying to persist the list of features returned from Deep Feature Synthesis directly to S3.  If persisting locally, I can use "ft.save_features(features,pathtofile)".  Is there anyway to pass in an S3 url to this method?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it can only write to the local disk. If you want to save to S3 and later download from S3, you can achieve it by writing the files to and from disk like this

```
import featuretools as ft
import boto

es = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)

feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                      target_entity="customers",
                      agg_primitives=["count"],
                      trans_primitives=["month"],
                      max_depth=1,
                      features_only=True)

# save features to disk
saved_features_file = "feature_defs"
ft.save_features(feature_defs, saved_features_file)

# upload to s3
s3_connection = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket('featuretools-static')
key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, saved_features_file)
key.set_contents_from_filename(saved_features_file)

# download from s3
downloaded_features_file = "feature_defs_downloaded"
key.get_contents_to_filename(downloaded_features_file)
feature_defs_s3 = ft.load_features(downloaded_features_file)

# test to make sure it works
feature_matrix = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(entityset=es, features=feature_defs_s3)
```

Comment: Thanks Max. This is what we are currently doing, just trying to avoid this intermediate step. Is this in the roadmap?  And is there a public link for the roadmap?  This is a great library.

Comment: there is a related issue up on github and I commented there about this question https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools/issues/73#issuecomment-479318826. please feel free to comment or endorse on GitHub. In general, GitHub issue are the best way to get a sense of the roadmap and let us know what you want built.